# Error while create view uncaught exception thrown by method called through reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional, and I was trying to create a view, but I got he error below suddenly,

There was an error running the selected code generator:

> uncaught exception thrown by method called through reflection
>   (Exception from HRESULT:0x0131604).

I have searched Google, but it is no luck.

Comment: Try Re-installing the VS2013

Comment: Thanks your reply during the Christmas holiday! Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 7):

Finally, I found the issue. It is wrong tag in web.confg, after I changed it to the correct one, it is working again!

Comment: Correct, I also had an issue in the web.config and I was facing this same issue, thanks for the answer, it saved my time.

Comment: I had this issue, and it turned out that I had two instances of appSettings - in general, it seems that having an invalid web.config will cause this error.